# JPEG to binary sent throught XBee and then decoded to JPEG again on a Windows/Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, image-processing, raspberry-pi, xbee

I am working on a project where I create an image with a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) and a bunch of sensors.

I need to encode that image so that it can be sent through an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) Pro S2B and then decoded in a Windows/Ubuntu machine. I can't just send the raw sensor data to the Windows/Ubuntu computer; I need the image itself. I need this to be in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) if possible, but any language is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the low bandwidth on the XBee module, you should really design your solution to push raw data from the Raspberry Pi and have the receiving end build the image.  If that doesn't fit your model due to some other design restriction, then take a look at the Open Source [python-xbee](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/) project.

You'll have to come up with a protocol for sending the data, since you just get binary streams between the two devices.  Since the stream ensures data integrity, you just need to work out framing and ensure that frames arrive in the correct order.

The sending node can make use of the Transmit Status frame to trigger sending of the next frame.  Transmit Status acknowledges that the remote node received the frame.

If you're open to using C, consider this [ANSI C XBee Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) on GitHub.